Why does Blaze-Persistence project count queries for pagination despite potential performance issues?
I'm using Blaze-Persistence and noticed that its offset pagination feature projects the count query as follows( concisely reduced ):
select *, (select count(*) from Entity)
from Entity e inner join Sub s on e.sub_id=s.id limit 5;

Doesn't this count query executed for each row potentially cause performance issues? I'm curious about why Blaze-Persistence uses this approach. What are the advantages of inlining the count query, and in what scenarios does this method provide benefits?
I understand there is an option to disable this feature, but I am interested in why it is used.
Thank you for your insights!

The decision behind a framework feature is mostly its developers. So you will likely have more luck asking this on their github page.  As for "What are the advantages of inlining the count query" to my knowledge, none, and if I see a framework doing that I would certainly disable it (or change the framework).

@JorgeCampos Thank you for your response. I will follow your advice and ask this on GitHub as well.

I'll answer on the GitHub discussion that you opened: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/discussions/1919

@ChristianBeikov I checked the response on the GitHub page and it helped me understand the issue. Thank you.
